# window hashchange event on internet explorer is not triggered

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, hashchange

i have a simple function on javascript where if the window position based on the url hashtag, so after the document is ready i execute my function normally, also i have add a hashchange event where i call the same function.

Everything works as expected except on internet explorer, if the user presses the enter on address bar without changing the hash (if he changes it works) then the function is not executed, any idea how to catch the event that the user pressed enter on the same url with same hashtag ?

Comment: "without changing the hash" then the `hash`**`change`** event shouldn't fire then, should it?

Comment: Does IE re-load the current page in that situation, or does simply “nothing happen”?

Comment: it seems that it refreshes the page because my fix function is not executed and fallback with hashtags default behavior of browser is executed

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses enter in the URL bar it loads the page, even if the adress wasn't changed. So, in your case it would simply refresh the page.

To capture this event you can use the `onbeforeunload` javascript event. This event gives you the ability to determine the navigation type. Use `event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type` to determine the type of navigation. This is working in IE, FF and Chrome.

```
function CallbackFunction(event) {
    if (event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        console.log("refreshing page");
    }
}

document.onbeforeunload = CallbackFunction;
```

Hopefully this was of some help to you!!

Comment: thank you for the info, the event is executed is not a solution in my problem as it is not triggering after the page load but before

Comment: actually now that i am testing on ie is not triggered at all, 
````
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
 if (event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type === 1) {
  // refreshing page
alert('refresh');
 }
};
````